# necessity of at() function over get(ch)

Tags: c++

what is the necessity to use at() function when we already have get(ch)/gets()/puts() to return a reference to a character  at specified position.

```
 // string::at
 //following is a code that explains the use of at() function

    #include <iostream>    //header file-iostream
    #include <string.h>    //header file -string.h,which contains all the string related functions
    using namespace std;   //for using cout & cin

    int main ()
    {
      string str ("Test string");     //initialize str
      for (unsigned i=0; i<str.length(); ++i)  //for loop for printing the string stored in str 
      {
        cout << str.at(i);        //displaying str using at() function
      }
      return 0;      //nothing is returned 
    }
```

Comment: These functions do totally different things. Would you mind sharing what you presume to be the alternative to `at` in your example?

Comment: both at() function and get(ch) are used to acess the string, character by character so what is the necessity of using at() function over get(ch)

Comment: Only `at` is actually a member of `std::string`. So how are the others supposed to be used to access characters of a given string?

Comment: `string` and `string.h` are completely different headers! Actually, there's no `string.h` in the C++ Standard.

Answer (score 0):

The point of [`std::string::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) is that is allows you access to a single character of the string and the index you specify.  If the index provided `>=` the `size()` of the string then an exception will be thrown.

This example just demonstrates that individual access.  If you actually wanted to print the string out you would just use

```
std::cout << str;
```